# openVPN - print to remote client

Tags: openvpn, cifs

```
    LAN (192.168.44.x)
      |          |
      |          |
   openVPN     WinXP ws1 (192.168.44.37)
   Server
(192.168.44.90)
  |          |
  |          |
  VPN1      VPN2
10.8.0.x   10.9.1.x
             |
             |
           remote winXP openVPN GUI client (10.9.1.2) - USB shared printer
```

i would like to print from WinXP ws1 to remote winXP openVPN GUI.

I can successfully connect to the VPN from remote winXP box and obtain a tun1 IP. I can also ping from winXP ws1 to remote winXP using: ping 10.9.1.2.

I can also remotely view remote winXP box from winXP ws1 with realVNC viewer. I connect to remote winXP by typing in 10.9.1.2

Why can't I map a printer from winXP ws1 to remote winXP?
network print wizard, connect to printer: \\10.9.1.2\shareName <--window cannot find printer

thanks!

tcpdump -i tun1 on openVPN server, when printer map is initiated

```
07:10:55.263641 IP 192.168.44.37.1598 > 10.9.1.2.microsoft-ds: Flags [S], seq 2980844745, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
07:10:55.263748 IP 192.168.44.37.1599 > 10.9.1.2.netbios-ssn: Flags [S], seq 2907893867, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
07:10:55.265304 IP 10.9.1.2.microsoft-ds > 192.168.44.37.1598: Flags [S.], seq 3332919477, ack 2980844746, win 16416, options [mss 1368,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
07:10:55.265448 IP 192.168.44.37.1598 > 10.9.1.2.microsoft-ds: Flags [.], ack 1, win 65535, length 0
07:10:55.265510 IP 10.9.1.2.netbios-ssn > 192.168.44.37.1599: Flags [S.], seq 1316159431, ack 2907893868, win 16416, options [mss 1368,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
07:10:55.265526 IP 192.168.44.37.1598 > 10.9.1.2.microsoft-ds: Flags [P.], seq 1:138, ack 1, win 65535, length 137WARNING: Short packet. Try increasing the snap length by 101
SMB PACKET: SMBnegprot (REQUEST)
```

Comment: Are you allowing those ports to be forwarded through? When you do a tcpdump on both sides of the tunnel, do you actually see that traffic passing through?

Comment: tcpdump -i tun1 on server...as soon as I try and map to the tun1 printer from winXP ws1, response posted above

Comment: If you're mapping by name, you may need a WINS server configured.

Comment: \\10.9.1.2\shareName this is what's used to define the map; tun1 IP not remote winXP computer name, so I wouldn't think WINS is needed?

Comment: i created a share on remote winXP vpn client, then successfully mapped to it from winXP ws1 using \\10.9.1.2\sharename....just can't fig. out why the printer map won't work??

Comment: The printer is shared, right?  Another computer on that network can see it?

Comment: yes, printer is shared. when mapping to the printer using the wizard, i enter \\10.9.1.2\ and the 2 shared printers are automatically shown. So, just to test, I changed one of the printer share names and tried to map it again using the wizard. I typed in \\19.9.1.2\ and the new share name i edited came up...so the printer shares are def. being broadcast over the VPN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ugh...finally found the problem, I was mapping the printer incorrectly from winXP ws1. 
In the add printer wizard, I need to select 'local printer' then add a 'local' port, which was \\10.9.1.2\printer.

All is working now.

Guess I figured that since remote winXP clients on remote LAN mapped to the printer using the wizard's 'network printer' option, you'd do it similarly through the vpn tunnel, but I guess not.